# When publish dialog says publish has finished, does that mean indexing has also finished as well?

Tags: publishing, caching

When Sitecore indicates that publishing has finished (via normal publish dialog) does this mean that subsequent indexing will also have finished, or does the dialog only report on publish status?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default web indexes uses `onPublishEndAsync` strategy.

It's executed asynchronously and depending on your application settings, can be distributed to all CD servers (e.g. with Lucene).

That's why the dialog only reports the publishing itself.

If you want to see if the reindexing is completed, you may want to try `/sitecore/admin/jobs.aspx` page. But those are only jobs executed on that particular server you're browsing, so it will not tell you if other servers still process their indexes.